# JSP内の変数宣言について

Tags: java, jsp, java-ee

JSP内である条件下の際は、固定のメッセージを表示したいのですが、
下記のようにKjnymdとMessageを定義して表示を試みたところ、
「cannot be resolved to a type」とのエラー表示がされました。

調べてみたところ、ServletとJspのクラスが一致してないためにKjnymdとMessageが
エラーとなっていたようなのですが、JSP内だけ完結することをできないのでしょうか。

```
<% var Kjnymd = "20231231"; 
   var Message = "日付をご確認ください";
　 if (JspUtil.notNull(infoBean.getDate()).equals(Kjnymd)) {
       Message 
   } else {
     infoBean.getDate())
     }
%>
```

エンジニア初心者で分かりにくい説明で申し訳ございませんが、
詳しい方がいらっしゃいましたらご教授いただけると助かります。

Answer (score 0):

質問コードにおける "cannot be resolved to a type" というエラーは、 `var` キーワードに対するものです。

JSPコンパイラーがJava10([JEP286](https://openjdk.org/jeps/286))の構文に対応していないことが原因です。

実行環境が記載されていないので[Tomcat9](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jasper-howto.html)を例にしますが、Tomcatではリンク先記載の通り `compilerSourceVM` 設定でJavaのソースバージョンを指定します。
そしてTomcat9のデフォルト値は `1.8` なので `var` を用いると質問文中のエラーになります。

この場合

- `compilerSourceVM` の設定値を `10` 以降に設定する
- (当然ですが、バージョン10以降のJavaVMで実行する)

ことでこのエラーは解消するはずです。
(対して[Tomcat10](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.1-doc/jasper-howto.html)のデフォルト値は `11` なので、デフォルトのままで動作するはずです)

Comment: ありがとうございます！
原因はバージョンの差異によるものなのですね。
TomcatとJavaソースのバージョン合わせることでエラーが解消され、
とても勉強になりました。